# What is meant by compatibility of orientation of $2$-manifold and a graph on that manifold?

Tags: graph-theory, algebraic-topology, manifolds, surfaces, simplicial-complex

Situation is the following. I have a genus $g$ surface $M_g$ and a graph $G$. There is an embedding $f: G \to M_g$ and, actually, $G$ triangulates $M_g$. Our graph has a cycle $C=(v_1,v_2,v_2)$ (graph $G$ is not directed, but we care about orientation of the cycles, i.e. $(v_1,v_2,v_3)\neq (v_3,v_2,v_1)$). This cycle is said to be "good" if $f(C)$ is the boundary of one component of $M_g\setminus f(G)$ and if the orientation on $f(C)$ induced by
$f$ from the orientation on $C$ is compatible with the orientation of $M_g$.

I struggle to understand the second part of the definition of a "good" cycle. Ok, there is orientation on $f(C)$, but what will we consider compatible orientation on $M_g$? Obviously, homological/smooth definitions are useless in this context. Should I consider orientation on every face of $G$, since it basically is $1$-skeleton of the simplicial complex which is triangulation of $M_g$? Then we do have an orientation on $M_g$, but it still is not very clear when it is compatible with orientation on $f(C)$. Does anyone know what is meant here?

Thank you.

Comment: Seems not well-defined to me. The curve $f(C)$ separates $M_g$ into two components, and it will inherit opposite orientations from both components. The only time you'd have a canonical orientation is e.g. if $C$ was the boundary of one of the triangles, but that doesn't always have to be the case.

Comment: @EthanDlugie well, not every cycle must be "good", it is a separate class of cycles. So what do you mean by canonical orientation here? What is the inherited orientation of each component?

Comment: If $M$ is an orientable manifold with boundary, there are lots of ways to define a "compatible" orientation on $\partial M$. In the case of surfaces, an orientation is like a little oriented loop based around each point in the interior. When those loops bump up against the boundary, they point in one direction. That gives the orientation on the boundary.
If $f(C)$ separates $M_g$ into two components, then the orientations it inherits from each component will be opposite.